# Workaround for java thread handle leak

Tags: java, multithreading, coldfusion, handles

I was wondering if anyone knows of a workaround to the handle leaks caused by creating and sleeping threads in java, see [JDK-8154063](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8154063).

I was thinking that maybe you could close open handles related to a finished thread manually using the jna [kernel32](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/platform/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32.html) class but have no idea where you would get the arguments for the CloseHandle method.

The only other fix i've found that works is to periodically restart the application but i'd prefer not to do that if possible.